# Peach Wit- extract flavoring or not

Tags: recipe, fruit

I have a peach wit that is going to be brewed tomorrow. It was a last minute decision to brew this for an upcoming summer barbecue. My question is this. Should i use fresh peaches in secondary? I only have approximately 30 days till the barbecue, I was considering using extract instead.

Comment: Are you force carbonating or bottle conditioning?

Answer (score 1):

The general principle is that the later you add it, the more fruit flavor will come through in the beer. Age, oxygen, heat and fermentation will "deaden" the delicate flavors. I'd suggest freezing the fruit to break down the cell walls plus kill bugs, then pitch slices into a mid-to-short secondary.

That said, extract might give you more punch, or more control if you are familiar with the particular extract.